# Rest client using Jersey returns empty object

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

im trying to develop a simple RESTful webservice client. Using java and the javax jersey+dependencies. My problem is when trying to convert from the XML the object comes in, it returns an empty object.

The test is a simple test. I whish to get the language with a specific id, from my test i can see that the XML im getting is the same as in a browser.

The code for the classes is as follows:

**Language**

```
package data;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "prestashop")
@XmlType
public class Language {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String iso_code;
    private String language_code;
    private boolean active;
    private boolean is_rtl;
    private String date_format_lite;
    private String date_format_full;

    public Language() {
    }

    public Language(String name, String iso_code, String date_format_lite, 
        String date_format_full) {

        this.name = name;
        this.iso_code = iso_code;
        this.date_format_lite = date_format_lite;
        this.date_format_full = date_format_full;
    }

    public Language(int id, String name, String iso_code, String language_code, 
        boolean active, boolean is_rtl, String date_format_lite, 
        String date_format_full) {

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.iso_code = iso_code;
        this.language_code = language_code;
        this.active = active;
        this.is_rtl = is_rtl;
        this.date_format_lite = date_format_lite;
        this.date_format_full = date_format_full;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getIso_code() {
        return iso_code;
    }

    public void setIso_code(String iso_code) {
        this.iso_code = iso_code;
    }

    public String getLanguage_code() {
        return language_code;
    }

    public void setLanguage_code(String language_code) {
        this.language_code = language_code;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public boolean isIs_rtl() {
        return is_rtl;
    }

    public void setIs_rtl(boolean is_rtl) {
        this.is_rtl = is_rtl;
    }

    public String getDate_format_lite() {
        return date_format_lite;
    }

    public void setDate_format_lite(String date_format_lite) {
        this.date_format_lite = date_format_lite;
    }

    public String getDate_format_full() {
        return this.date_format_full;
    }

    public void setDate_format_full(String date_format_full) {
        this.date_format_full = date_format_full;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
         return "Language ["
                + "id=" + id + ", "
                + "name=" + name + ", "
                + "iso_code=" + iso_code + ", "
                + "language_code=" + language_code + ", "
                + "active=" + active + ", "
                + "is_rtl=" + is_rtl + ", "
                + "date_format_lite=" + date_format_lite + ", "
                + "date_format_full=" +  date_format_full+ ","
                + " ]";
   }
}
```

**Main**

```
package webservicetest2;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter;
import data.Language;
import java.net.URI;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;

public class WebServiceTest2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        try {
            ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
            Client client = Client.create(config);
            client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("KEY", ""));
            WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());

            System.out.println(service.path("languages")
                    .path("7")
                    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
                    .get(String.class));

            Language language;
            language = (Language) service.path("languages")
                    .path("7")
                    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
                    .get(Language.class);
            System.out.println(language.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static URI getBaseURI() {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/api").build();
    }
}
```

**The output**

```
run:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<language>
    <id><![CDATA[7]]></id>
    <name><![CDATA[Danish]]></name>
    <iso_code><![CDATA[da]]></iso_code>
    <language_code><![CDATA[da]]></language_code>
    <active><![CDATA[1]]></active>
    <is_rtl><![CDATA[0]]></is_rtl>
    <date_format_lite><![CDATA[Y-m-d]]></date_format_lite>
    <date_format_full><![CDATA[Y-m-d H:i:s]]></date_format_full>
</language>
</prestashop>

Language [id=0, name=null, iso_code=null, language_code=null, active=false, is_rtl=false, date_format_lite=null, date_format_full=null, ]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

As you can see the XML im getting back has an object but the print of the object is an empty object. So something is wrong.

Sorry if simular question have been asked but havent been able to find any.

Comment: For the googlers hitting this: Please read http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessType.html and check that you have for every getter also a setter defined. - @Martin: This seems to be the case in your example, so there must be another reason why your example fails.